# Swift - Reading text: line1 = variable, line2 = variable, ect

Tags: swift

I'm creating a program with saved accounts. I'm writing to the file line by line with the user information (line 1 = username, line2 = password, line3 = displayname). I'm good with reading the text file but how do I decode each line to a different variable? So line1 = usernameVariable, line2 = passwordVariable, line3 = displaynameVariable.

Here's how I'm reading the data

```
if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {        
    let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)
    //reading
    do {
        let text2 = try String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: .utf8)
        outText = text2
    } catch {/* error handling here */}
}
```

and this is what print(outText) gets:

n1
u1
p1
x
n2
u2
p2

n = nickname, u = username, p = password.

I simply want to assign whatever u1 reads to a username variable, etc.

Comment: Do you need a text file in this specific format for other purposes? There are much better ways to persist your data than using a plain text file.

Comment: Not at all! I'm fairly new to coding in xcode/swift so I felt this would be easiest to distinguish the separate variables. Would comas or similar be more valuable? I have 3 separate accounts, all with usernames, passwords, and display names. Just trying to keep things pretty i guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a text file is not what you should be doing for this. There are many more appropriate ways store and retrieve your data. A text file is very low on the list of the best options.

First, declare a `struct` to hold each entry:

```
struct UserData {
    let username: String
    let password: String
    let displayName: String
}
```

Since you wish to persist this data, make the struct `Codable`:

```
struct UserData: Codable {
```

Now you can use `JSONEncoder` to encode the user data list to `Data` and then write the data to a file. And use `JSONDecoder` to read back the list of user data.

```
// You array of users
let users = [ UserData(username: "Bob", password: "pass", displayName: "Hello") ]
// Get the path
let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let url = dir.appendingPathComponent("userdata")

// Code to save the array of data    
do {
    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(users)
    try data.write(to: url)
} catch {
    print("error: \(error)")
}

// Code to read the list of user data
do {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    let newUsers = try JSONDecoder().decode([UserData].self, from: data)
    print(newUsers)
} catch {
    print("error: \(error)")
}
```

Now you don't need to do any string parsing yourself. This happens to use JSON to persist the data but that detail is not really important.

Comment: Outstanding, thorough answer. (Voted)

Comment: You are fantastic, thank you so much for this! Last annoying bit, but how would I convert the read names to data in the app? I'm not quite sure what to look up to find out myself?  I've got reading down pat, just not sure now how to make username1 into a variable.

Comment: Once you have the array, you can access it something like `newUsers[0].username`

Comment: I really appreciate you. You've gone above and beyond. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
let all = str.components(separatedBy:"\n")
```

then loop for every 3 and fill say a struct object